# How to make Emacs 24 render font like Sublime Text 2?

Tags: emacs, fonts, sublimetext2

The following graph shows a comparison between Sublime Text 2 (left) and Emacs 24 (right, installed from homebrew) on how they render texts on my Mac. They all use Monaco with normal weight, but as you can see, Emacs renders text in a somewhat aliased way. The problem didn't show up when I was using Emacs 23 on my Mac. I'm wondering if there is any way to fix it.

[image: Font rendering]

Comment: ZelluX, what's the font size for the SublimeText font?

Comment: @wvxvw The two softwares both run on the same Mac, and iTerm display the font similar to Sublime Text 2, so I guess it may be something wrong with my current Emacs since its previous version works fine on my Mac.

Comment: @MahmoudAbdelkader I've set font size of both softwares to Monaco-13.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fix the problem by using compiled [Emacs For Mac OS X](http://emacsformacosx.com/) instead, and it renders texts well. The Emacs version I mentioned in the question was built from git repository, I guess that was the problem since it was too cutting edge.

#### Update:

The bug seems to be introduced in the latest Emacs build, see report [#11484](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=11484) [#12996](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=12996) [#13106](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=13106).

Comment: how do you make emacs look like sublime text?

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade to Emacs 24.3, they fixed this bug.

Comment: how do you make emacs look like sublime text?